# locking button press in blender game engine

Tags: scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am trying to figure out how to lock a button press until the player interacts with a object which then unlocks the button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

add property to the door which tells when the door is locked or unlocked .  then add trigger which sends message "unlockdoor" (and unlocks the door(sets locked to 0)) . then add animation